# how to get user input in same line in python whenever there is some condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and one thing i was wondering to do is to take user input like this:-

```
    >> 4 # This is the Number of test Case
    >> 1
    >> 2 5
    >> 2 7
    >> 2 9
```

so on and so forth.
so I tried this way:-

```
Q=int(input())
for i in range(Q):
    x = int(input())
    if x == 1:
       #do something  
    elif x==2:
        item=int(input()).split()
```

but after doing this i am not getting my desired output,it is like:-

```
    >>4
    >>1
    >>2
    >>5
    >>2
    >>7
    >>2
    >>9
    >>1
```

Please help me out i am new to python!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check on the length of what you read, when reading value of `x = int(input())`.
Read the value of x as string.

```
Q=int(input())
for i in range(Q):
    x = input()
    if len(x) == 1:
      print(int(x))
    elif len(x) > 1:
        item=x.split()
        print(int(item[0]))
        print(int(item[1]))
```

Comment: Thanku so much it worked i am trying to getting your logic now!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot split an `int`.Once you change that rest of the code is working fine.

```
Q=int(input())
for i in range(Q):
    x = int(input())
    if x == 1:
        pass
        #do something
    elif x==2:
        print "enter string"
        item=input().split()

print item
```

Input:`5
1
2
enter string
"hello world"
3
4
5`